# getting error on using jstree in modal in multiple opening and close

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I'm trying to use [ngJstTree](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree) for developing jsTree.

my tree is in a modal.
when I close the modal an reopen it , I have the problem below:

the first and the second time It's OK , but when I open it for the 3rd time , during DND , the error below ecounters.

> $scope.treeInstance.jstree(...).get_json is not a function

adding `destroy()` API , in the time of closing modal , has no effect on It.

please Help me on It;